# Where else you can you shop except citadel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Are there Shops outside Citadel / Normandy where you can go to and find Upgrades, Armor etc?

Or are those the only places to get rid of your credits in ME3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *find* upgrades on missions, but the Citadel and the Normandy are the only places that have shops in Mass Effect 3.